# ERROR AFTER CHANGING NAMESPACE OF ASP.net MVC PROJECT

Tags: namespaces

Recently i have changed the namespace using the project properties. After that, application was compiling successfully, but at run-time it throws error  "The type or namespace name ‘sample’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".
**Error:**
Line 23:     using System.Web.Routing;
Line 24:     using Sample;

**Source File:** c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files......\App_Web_index.cs    Line:

I tried to locate the string  “using Sample” and didn’t find anywhere in my solution.
Tried removing the temporary files from framework folder **but no luck.**

Answer (score 10):

The problem was with my **Web.config** file

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
 <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Sample" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

I just replaced the old value "Sample" with new namespace name, and everything starts working again.

Comment: this may work at first, but somehow (the next times or sometimes) the old value is still **cached** somewhere and VS (***Intelligently***) uses that cached value, cannot stand this bug.

Answer (score 3):

Answering so that anyone else has the same issue. There another web.config file under views. please change it there too.